# Visualize normals of object created in Geometry node

Tags: normals, geometry-nodes

For debugging purpose, I'd like to visualize the normals of an object created in the Geometry Node. Unfortunately, I can only enable it (via the overlay menu) for regular objects:

[image]

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

With Blender 3.0, this works if I use cylinder, but not if I use Mesh line:

With lines:

[image]

With Cylinder:

[image]

Do you think it is a bug from Blender 3.0?

Comment: OK for me in 3.0.. details [here](https://imgur.com/a/hVKhb3x)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's impossible without applying the modifier, unfortunately. The data created by the Geometry Nodes modifier seems to not be available to the edit-mode overlays.

Here's a proposal with the [Normal node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/normal.html), but you'll have to use at least Blender V3.1 Beta.

You can plug this at the end of your modifier stack :

[image]

If you plug an input into the Mesh Line offset, you can change the normal length interactively.

[image]

If you want your visualizer to not piggyback on the original object geometry, you can use an [Object Info](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/render/shader_nodes/input/object_info.html) node.

[image]

You can even visualize entire collections with a [Collection info](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/collection_info.html) node.

[image]

That way any object you'll add to the collection will automatically display its normals.

[image]

Comment: i cannot believe you stole my idea - realized before i got it - you broke my heart  +1 ....but with crying eyes....

Comment: Hi! Works fine in 3.0 stable, for me..

Comment: Oh I thought the normal node was not part of the 3.0 release, my bad. Hehe sorry @Chris don't be sad ! Maybe you can expand on the idea and tell us how to do it for face and edge normals, too ? :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, cool idea! Not sure why, but on blender 3.0 I can't make it work when using lines (a single line is displayed), but it does work when using tiny cylinders.