# How to keep the procedural texture unchanged in the pose mode?

Tags: animation, materials, normals, procedural, pose-mode

This question is related to the [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/297969/how-to-mask-texture-with-normal).

The shader material is setup based on the dot product between the surface normal and a vector <1,1,1> as the following screenshot shows:

[image]

In the *Object mode*, the shader material is unchanged after rotating the torus:

[image]

Now, the torus is parented to an armature. In the *Pose mode*, rotating the bone can change the shape of the shader material as the following screenshot shows:

[image]

How do I avoid this change please?

By the way, I hope that there is a better way to do this, other than baking the material.

[image]